# How to pin variables to positions in bar graphs in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function in R that makes a bar graph, but the function places the bars alphabetically.  I would like to be able to pin the "Placebo" bar to the left position so that any bar graphs automatically read "Placebo" "**treatment**".  Would the `reorder` command be what I need or is there some other way to coerce "Placebo" to stay on the left side?

Ideally I would like to alter the function itself rather than alter the position individually, as I have a fair number of these bar graphs to produce.

Thanks!

[working graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cp3Xr.png) [not working graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoYtO.png)

---

The data structure is similar to this:

```
    T2          model_label     model difference p_two_tail p_one_tail  difference2 star p_label treatment  outcome
1   trust_lo~2  trust_localgvt  1A    20.401650  0.1829079  0.09145395  +20.4       ^    +20.4^  Placebo     44.57343
2   trust_lo~2  trust_localgvt  1A    20.401650  0.1829079  0.09145395  +20.4       ^    +20.4^  Generic GOTV 64.97508
```

```
draw_bar_auto <- 
  function(data, 
           x = treatment,
           y = outcome,
           plot_title = model_label,
           p_label = p_label,
           fill_color = c("gold", "darkslateblue"),
           fontsize_magnitude = 7,
           line_size = 1.5,
           linetype = "solid",
           fontface = "bold",
           fontsize_pvalue = 8,
           ...) {

    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)
    plot_title <- enquo(plot_title)
    p_label <- enquo(p_label)

    # Use the variable `model_label` as plot title
    plot_title <- data %>%
      select(!!plot_title) %>%
      pull()

    # Stores the value for "outcome" variables to calculate whiskers position
    whiskers <- data %>%
      select(!!y) %>%
      pull()

    # Stores the p-value label
    p_value_label <- data %>%
      select(!!p_label) %>%
      slice(1)

    ggplot(data) +
      # Plot a bar chart, `treatment` variable on x axis, `outcome` variable on y axis
      geom_col(aes(x = !!x, y = !!y, 
                   # Vary fill and outline color by `treatment` variable
                   fill = !!x, color = !!x)) +
      # Label outcome variable values on each bar, print only one decimal place
      geom_text(aes(x = !!x, y = !!y, label = sprintf('%.1f', !!y)),
                # make vertical adjustment, set font size
                vjust = -1, size = fontsize_magnitude) +
      # Set y axis range (0 to 100 in this case)
      coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 110), clip = "off") +
      # Set y axis ticks break (none in this case)
      scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0, 100)) +
      # Color for bar chart fill
      scale_fill_manual(values = fill_color) +
      # Color for bar chart outline
      scale_color_manual(values = c("grey30", "grey30")) +
      # Plot title and axis labels
      labs(title = "", 
           # Remove labels for x and y axis
           x = "", y = "") +
      # Draw horizontal line
      annotate("segment", 
               # x coord position: starts on 1st bar, ends on 2nd bar
               x = 1, xend = 2, 
               # height of horizontal bar: height of taller bar + 25
               y = whiskers[2] + 15, yend = whiskers[2] + 15, 
               size = line_size, linetype = linetype) +
      # Draw left whisker
      annotate("segment", x = 1, xend = 1,
               # starts at: left bar + 15. ends at: height of taller bar + 25
               y = whiskers[1] + 10, yend = whiskers[2] + 15, 
               size = line_size, linetype = linetype) +
      # Draw right whisker
      annotate("segment", x = 2, xend = 2,
               # starts at: right bar + 15. ends at: height of taller bar + 25
               y = whiskers[2] + 10, yend = whiskers[2] + 15, 
               size = line_size, linetype = linetype) +
      # Add effect size and p-value
      annotate("text", x = 1.5, 
               # position of text: height of taller bar + 32 (i.e. horizontal bar + 7)
               y = whiskers[2] + 20, 
               # text shown: values stored in p_value_label 
               label = p_value_label, 
               size = fontsize_pvalue, fontface = fontface, ...)

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try (assuming your data is called `df`):

```r
df$treatment = factor(df$treatment, levels = c("Placebo","Generic GOTV"))
```

And you can check the order using:

```r
levels(df$treatment)
```